# add image CSS : local file or url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am working on a `HTML` Webpage with `CSS` and `Ajax`. I would like to add an image and I know I can do it by adding the image in a folder inside my project or add it with an URL so which one is better method to use, I mean what should be the inconvinients of each method that would make me prefer one to the other ?

Comment: The standard method for adding an image to a web page is by linking to it with `<img src="path/to/file.jpg" />`. Usually you would host the image on your webspace. It's not really clear what you're asking...

Comment: I would go for the local way.

Comment: How do you add an image to a webpage by putting in in a folder in your project?

Comment: if you mean local images vs externally hosted images then you should use externally hosted images with local image backup mechanism, or host it locally and use a CDN, there are free ones like incapsula and cloudflare available

Comment: Every image you use needs to be added with a URL

Comment: you mean local (relative) URL versus external (other site) URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it in a local file because:

1) Relative paths;

2) You have more control on it (what if the other site is down?);

3) You don't have to read 1000+ pages of terms of use in which the external website may say that they will own your images if you put them there.

You should use external hosting because:

1) It is cheaper (sometimes free);

2) You can free up bandwidth (especially if you have a lot of images);

3) Using relative paths is not always better (and can cause issues with migrations, see the comment)

Deciding which one you would use depends on your needs. If you have few images, it is better to store them locally. If you have a lot of images and don't have the resources to host them, it is better to use external services.

Comment: You should nuance your answer though. **Against this reasoning:** (1)When you don't have a lot of webstorage available and lots of images, it could be preferable to store them  somewhere else (eg. Flickr, imgur). (2)Also, I've known Wordpress migrations to mess up the filepaths (requiring DB changes), which wouldn't have been the case with external sites.